# Is it necessary the app camScanner should be installed in my Android Device

Tags: android, ios

First I appreciate the Application The [CamScanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner&hl=en)
I have intended to implement this in my app.

camScanner says that they have provided the Open API 
i.e

*Enable your apps to digitalize paper documents with cutting-edge image processing technologies*

https://dev.camscanner.com/

have any body implemented the camScanner in your apps, I have a question

Upon agreement signing with camScanner, what they give us any sdk or library or somthing like that

Important Question

**IF they gave any sdk/library Upon agreement signing with camScanner then is it necessary the app camScanner should be installed in my device to scan the image and get edges and cropped functionality, Or its does not required.**

Comment: According to me, No. It is not necessary.

Comment: @Tushar thanks for comment but i think its required to install the app. Waiting for sure answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It is required to have an instance of the free version of camscanner installed. I am using this API myself, both for Android and iOS.